# Weird behavior when downloading my module

Tags: go, module, go-modules

Whenever I download a module i made (https://github.com/torbenconto/plutus) using go get, it doesn't let me use any of the sub packages until i run go mod tidy on the project i downloaded it to. Please help me I have no idea how to fix this!

This is the go.mod of my module

```
module github.com/torbenconto/plutus/api

go 1.21

toolchain go1.21.1

require (
    github.com/gin-gonic/gin v1.9.1
    github.com/torbenconto/plutus v1.3.0
)

require (
    github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery v1.8.1 // indirect
    github.com/andybalholm/cascadia v1.3.2 // indirect
    github.com/antchfx/htmlquery v1.3.0 // indirect
    github.com/antchfx/xmlquery v1.3.18 // indirect
    github.com/antchfx/xpath v1.2.5 // indirect
    github.com/bytedance/sonic v1.10.2 // indirect
    github.com/chenzhuoyu/base64x v0.0.0-20230717121745-296ad89f973d // indirect
    github.com/chenzhuoyu/iasm v0.9.1 // indirect
    github.com/gabriel-vasile/mimetype v1.4.3 // indirect
    github.com/gin-contrib/sse v0.1.0 // indirect
    github.com/go-playground/locales v0.14.1 // indirect
    github.com/go-playground/universal-translator v0.18.1 // indirect
    github.com/go-playground/validator/v10 v10.16.0 // indirect
    github.com/gobwas/glob v0.2.3 // indirect
    github.com/goccy/go-json v0.10.2 // indirect
    github.com/gocolly/colly/v2 v2.1.0 // indirect
    github.com/golang/groupcache v0.0.0-20210331224755-41bb18bfe9da // indirect
    github.com/golang/protobuf v1.5.3 // indirect
    github.com/json-iterator/go v1.1.12 // indirect
    github.com/kennygrant/sanitize v1.2.4 // indirect
    github.com/klauspost/cpuid/v2 v2.2.6 // indirect
    github.com/leodido/go-urn v1.2.4 // indirect
    github.com/mattn/go-isatty v0.0.20 // indirect
    github.com/modern-go/concurrent v0.0.0-20180306012644-bacd9c7ef1dd // indirect
    github.com/modern-go/reflect2 v1.0.2 // indirect
    github.com/pelletier/go-toml/v2 v2.1.1 // indirect
    github.com/saintfish/chardet v0.0.0-20230101081208-5e3ef4b5456d // indirect
    github.com/temoto/robotstxt v1.1.2 // indirect
    github.com/twitchyliquid64/golang-asm v0.15.1 // indirect
    github.com/ugorji/go/codec v1.2.12 // indirect
    golang.org/x/arch v0.6.0 // indirect
    golang.org/x/crypto v0.17.0 // indirect
    golang.org/x/net v0.19.0 // indirect
    golang.org/x/sys v0.15.0 // indirect
    golang.org/x/text v0.14.0 // indirect
    google.golang.org/appengine v1.6.8 // indirect
    google.golang.org/protobuf v1.32.0 // indirect
    gopkg.in/yaml.v3 v3.0.1 // indirect
)
```

And this is the error code i get when hovering over the red underlined import of my module
could not import github.com/torbenconto/plutus/quote (no required module provides package "github.com/torbenconto/plutus/quote")compilerBrokenImport

The issue is resolved when i run go mod tidy in the project that downloaded the module.
The go.mod in the project that downloaded it turns from looking like this before running go mod tidy

```
module test

go 1.21.1

require (
    github.com/torbenconto/plutus v1.4.1 // indirect
)
```

to this after running it

```
module test

go 1.21.1

require github.com/torbenconto/plutus v1.4.1

require (
    github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery v1.8.1 // indirect
    github.com/andybalholm/cascadia v1.3.2 // indirect
    github.com/antchfx/htmlquery v1.3.0 // indirect
    github.com/antchfx/xmlquery v1.3.18 // indirect
    github.com/antchfx/xpath v1.2.5 // indirect
    github.com/gobwas/glob v0.2.3 // indirect
    github.com/gocolly/colly/v2 v2.1.0 // indirect
    github.com/golang/groupcache v0.0.0-20210331224755-41bb18bfe9da // indirect
    github.com/golang/protobuf v1.5.3 // indirect
    github.com/kennygrant/sanitize v1.2.4 // indirect
    github.com/saintfish/chardet v0.0.0-20230101081208-5e3ef4b5456d // indirect
    github.com/temoto/robotstxt v1.1.2 // indirect
    golang.org/x/net v0.19.0 // indirect
    golang.org/x/text v0.14.0 // indirect
    google.golang.org/appengine v1.6.8 // indirect
    google.golang.org/protobuf v1.31.0 // indirect
    gopkg.in/yaml.v3 v3.0.1 // indirect
)
```

Please Help.

I have tried to run go mod tidy in the project to no avail along with many other things i found on google. So far nothing has worked after a few hours of troubleshooting.

Comment: Start by using proper module names. Neither test nor main is a suitable module name. Second: There is no need (or even the possibility) to "download a module". If you want to use a package you have to add that _package_ to your dependencies via "go get". You have to do this for each package or call go mod tidy (as you seem to know). There is nothing to fix. Just call go mod tidy as this will "do the right thing" (especially if you are unsure how modules, packages and versioning work actually).

Comment: BTW: module github.com/torbenconto/plutus/api requiring module github.com/torbenconto/plutus looks pretty weird. You probably should work through go.dev/doc, especially the Tutorials describing how to work with packages and modules.

Comment: The module names test and main were for testing the module, they were only temporary. By download the module i meant retrieve it and add it to dependencies. The api was supposed to be a seperate repo all together and has since been moved to that. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Again. Do not name your module neither main nor test, not even temporary or "for testing". Adding a module to the dependencies doesn't leave go.mod and go.sum in a final, usable state (that's why you are encouraged to add packages) and go mod tidy fixes that. Note that "go get" doesn't "download" modules (to some certain degree some things are "downloaded" during go get). What you probably think of when saying "download": This happens during go build or go download.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. I do not have to run tidy after go getting github.com/torbenconto/plutus and importing github.com/torbenconto/plutus/quote.

Comment: @Peter I think you can't reproduce it because I fixed the issue, thats great to know that the fix is working though. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was fixed by importing the modules that were used by the sub packages (colly-go in this case) in my main file (plutus.go) causing go get to retrieve all the needed modules.

Answer (score 0):

Seems structuring is wrong. Ideally 1 go project should have single `go.mod` and `go.sum` files.

```
|- github.com/torbenconto/plutus
|--- go.mod
|--- go.sum
|---internal
|---api
     |----api.go
```

You've added the files twice in `github.com/torbenconto/plutus/api` and `github.com/torbenconto/plutus`.

Remove go.mod and go.sum from `api` folder. and use import like this `github.com/torbenconto/plutus/api` if you wanted to use an api.

Also package name of `api` wrong. It should like `package api`.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the flaw in my project, unfortunately this doesen't answer my original question. My issue is that whenever a user downloads this through go get, all of the dependencies specified in go.mod are not downloaded for the user and they then have to run go mod tidy to get the plutus/quote package to work. Further help would be appreciated. Thanks.